# How to get the element that has focus in selinium Webdriver using C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

During the testing of a webpage

after a number of operations i need to check using selenium if the focus is on the right element does anybody have an idea how can it be done ? (C#)
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the targetlocator as this:

```
webdriver.switchTo().activeElement();
```

From the Selenium documentation:

> ```
> activeElement()
> ```
>
> Switches to the element that currently has focus within the document
>   currently "switched to", or the body element if this cannot be
>   detected.

[Selenium Documentation Source](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#activeElement--)

Comment: Thanks for the answer its working , and thanks for the Documentation as well !

Comment: I tried the link this morning on April 18, 2019, but I get a 404 error.